# Does 'nature' in French express Nature as in the Natural world as well as in human nature?

Tags: vocabulaire

In English the word 'nature' can be used to describe Nature, the impersonal force of the natural world; and also in human nature. Is there something similar in French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [*nature*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/nature) in French has all the meanings of [*nature*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nature) in English.  It is even possible to personalize the meaning "creative and controlling force in the universe" by giving it a capital first letter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Semantic Altas](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/en/index.html) they are semantically equals.

(the fact that one figure is upside down is the result of an arbitrary sign).
[image]